# HTML CSS Modal: Position fixed not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a Modal
I have given the Background component `position:fixed` still its starting from the toggle button

when `position:fixed` is active:

[image]

when `position:fixed` is not active:

[image]

```
const Background = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

```
 <div>
      {' '}
      {showModal ? (
        <Background>
          <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
            <ModalImg src={require('./modal.jpg')} alt='camera' />
            <ModalContent>
              <h1>Are you ready?</h1>
              <p>Get exclusive access to our next launch.</p>
              <button>Join Now</button>
            </ModalContent>
            <CloseModalButton
              aria-label='Close modal'
              onClick={() => setShowModal((prev) => !prev)}
            />
          </ModalWrapper>
        </Background>
      ) : null}
    <div/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the  tag used in the last segment of code as a wrapper/parent is not style neutral, it has some default styling which is causing such problem.

Replace is with <> </>

```
 <>
      {' '}
      {showModal ? (
        <Background>
          <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
            <ModalImg src={require('./modal.jpg')} alt='camera' />
            <ModalContent>
              <h1>Are you ready?</h1>
              <p>Get exclusive access to our next launch.</p>
              <button>Join Now</button>
            </ModalContent>
            <CloseModalButton
              aria-label='Close modal'
              onClick={() => setShowModal((prev) => !prev)}
            />
          </ModalWrapper>
        </Background>
      ) : null}
    </>
```

And now everything works fine!